# How to check the existence of specific file names and exit statuses? (and if unsuccessful loop until successful)

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting

I'm a bash scripting rookie and have been googling this scenario for about six hours to no avail. I have found segments of what I need but no comprehensive solution.

Here is the problem:
I need to write some code that will be able to check that 3 files exist (`file1.txt`, `file2.csv` and `file3.log`). Before proceeding however, I need to confirm that `file3.log` has stopped writing (this is to confirm that the script that creates the 3 files has finished successfully).

checking the existence of these files seems easy enough using something like:

```
if [ -f -e /path/to/file/file1.txt && /path/to/file/file2.csv && /path/to/file/file3.log]
then
# somehow check the exit status of file3.log
if [$? !=0]
#somehow loop (maybe every 5 minutes) until $?=0
done
```

OR

I was also thinking can I just avoid all of this together and just check the exit status of the initial script? but I wasn't sure because if there was some sort of failure and the files weren't created then that would be a serious problem because the next part of the scanning process takes about 2 days...

Sorry if this might seem like a stupid question, I'm so deep in the google "if-until-exit-zero-else..." hole that I have no idea what to do from here.

Comment: is `file3.log` a program, or the output of a program?

Comment: Its the output of the initial script @ctrl-alt-delor

Comment: You can't check the exit status of a file, you can see when it is written to, created, deleted etc. But it has no concept of exit to check. You have to check the exit status of the program that is writing to it. However if the writer writes a distinctive word at the end (this is an inefficient test), or keeps the file open, until the process exits. Then you can monitor it.

Answer (score 0):

To check that a named program or a script has finished, use the command:

```
wait $(pgrep program-name)
```

Comment: Note: this requires `program-name` to be a child of the current shell.

Comment: Thanks! Ill give this a try and get back to you!

Comment: Thanks harry this worked perfectly without any messing around